# Which Formula can i use for to auto fill my table if i predefine it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel

if party name match with my predefine list on the right side it select automaticity manager name and zone of the party name in the left side. image is attached. please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCjC1.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Answer (score 1):

In cell B2:
`=VLOOKUP(A2;$F$2:$H$100;2)`

In cell C2:
`=VLOOKUP(A2;$F$2:$H$100;3)`

P.S H100 can be changed depending on your table size